# jenkins-cli get node doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-cli

I have created a jenkins node using jenkins-cli create node command. The node gets created successfully and I could see it in the web interface.

```
NODE_NAME=$1
LABEL=$2
cat <<EOF | java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myjenkins/jenkins/ create-node --username userId --password testPwd $1
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<slave>
  <name>${NODE_NAME}</name>
  <description></description>
  <remoteFS>/Users/jenkins1/Desktop/workspace</remoteFS>
  <numExecutors>1</numExecutors>
  <mode>EXCLUSIVE</mode>
  <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
  <launcher class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher" plugin="ssh-slaves@1.22">
    <host>test</host>
    <port>22</port>
    <credentialsId>test</credentialsId>
    <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries>
    <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime>
    <sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.KnownHostsFileKeyVerificationStrategy"/>
  </launcher>
  <label>${LABEL}</label>
  <nodeProperties>
    <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
      <envVars serialization="custom">
        <unserializable-parents/>
        <tree-map>
          <default>
            <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
          </default>
          <int>1</int>
          <string>MVN_REPOS</string>
          <string>/Users/jenkins1/Desktop/workspace</string>
        </tree-map>
      </envVars>
    </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
  </nodeProperties>
</slave>
EOF
```

But when I try to get the node after it has been created using jenkins-cli I get no such node error. However, I am able to get the node after saving the configuration through Jenkins UI. Could you please help me to fix this error.

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myjenkins/jenkins/ get-node 'tests' --username userId --password testPwd

ERROR: No such node 'tests'

Answer (score 1):

When you create a node or job from the cli, most times you have to return to Jenkins UI and run "Manage Jenkins >> Reload Configuration From Disk", otherwise cli changes sometime remain ineffective. Have you already tried doing this?

Answer (score -1):

@funkfan As I have mentioned in my post, I am able to get the node after saving the configuration through Jenkins UI. I have even tried jenkins-cli reload-configuration command before saving the configuration from the Jenkins UI without any luck.